# different levels in code igniter?

Tags: codeigniter

im all new to framework.

so the structure of code igniter looks like:

system
system/application

the system folder is code igniter's base folder right? so if they in the future releases a new version i just put application in the new system folder and its upgraded right?

does this mean that i shouldn't put new files and so on in the system folder? cause some code could be used for other applications and i want to put them under the current application im developing, not inside the application folder.

i want my application's classes to extend my base system's classes which in turn extend code igniter's base system class.

so there are 3 levels. so how could i accomplish this? where to put the system level between CI and my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core framework files are located in SYSTEM/CODEIGNITER.

Your application files are mostly located in SYSTEM/APPLICATION

You can extend CodeIgniter by putting files into SYSTEM/LIBRARIES folder. For example the default prefix for own files extending core framework is MY so you will have my_model.php inside `class MY_Model extends Model {` then in your SYSTEM/APPLICATION/MODELS you can have user.php and inside the file `class User extends MY_Model {` This is very basic example. You can read more here - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: ok so when i upgrade to next CI version i have to move all MY_ classes from SYSTEM/LIBRARIES to the new one?

Comment: Yes. You can change the default extension prefix MY to something else from the config.php so be careful. There are other ways to extend CodeIgniter mentioned in the article I gave you above. But the general case is that you will never change anything inside the SYSTEM/APPLICATION

Answer (score 0):

With most of their upgrades you can just copy the application folder into the new codeigniter directory.  Any changes outside of the application folder will need to be carried over as well.  Additionally, you should test the upgrade locally prior to upgrading your production site in case the changes break your code.